# Install GCC for Mac? 10.5.8

Tags: mac, gcc

I am trying to install GCC on Mac. I only need the C standard and whatever is required to compile bison. I see a 2.5GB file that will take me all day. I can't start it today so maybe tomorrow. Is there a smaller option?

I am using Mac OS X 10.5.8.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can find some binaries online but downloading [XCode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html) from Apple is really the best option (even if the file is a bit huge)

Answer (score 2):

Your Mac installation disks have a version of XCode on them that you can install, though it's likely not as new as what you can download.

Without knowing what you need to compile bison for, I don't know if a system like [homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) is adequate or not, but it may be something you can look into.

Answer (score 1):

Building GCC on MacOS X has usually not worked for me (I think I got it done once; I've compiled it on Solaris many times) - so XCode is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you have XCode installed, In XCode, go to the XCode menu, followed by Preferences, Downloads, and then click on the Install button.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just ran into this issue, and wanted to share what I found out. If you install macports then you can pull an entire gnu build-essential suite from the repo's.

Comment: just a glitch - macports requires XCode installed

Answer (score 0):

Though it does not answer the question for 10.5, for next versions (10.6 & 10.7 at the moment of writing) there is a GCC installer [available here](http://blog.strug.de/de/) ( found it via [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360110/installing-gcc-to-mac-os-x-leopard-without-installing-xcode) ).

I think it may be useful for those who will look for the same for the current versions of OS X.

I did try it myself and am using it along with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to compile and install unix tools. ( Sometimes it needs some LSF-style manual tweaking, but hey -- nobody's perfect ) )

Answer (score -2):

If someone needs it, I bundled GCC 4.2 and CLI tools (make, etc) from official Xcode 3.1.4 package into one archive of 64 Mo. You can download it from the link below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ZuzZ8mn9xRVVdOTkpTckdNdEk/view?usp=sharing